# Meteor google analytics

Tags: meteor, google-analytics

I have used [this](https://github.com/okgrow/analytics/) package for analytics.
My analytics is working for page view but for click event not working. I have written following code:

```
analytics.track("click", {
    eventName: "downloadImage",
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, but it should work something like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events = {
  'click button': function (event, template) {
    analytics.track("Bought Ticket", {
      eventName: "Wine Tasting",
      couponValue: 50
    });
  }
}
```

What this does is tracks each time the button is clicked as a "Bought Ticket" event.

Comment: my code is same as yours.  Just event is "click" instead of  "Bought Ticket"

Comment: So you should see a click event somewhere in your Google Analytics. It can be hard to find sometimes

Comment: Now I tried.Acttually It just make the entry of click event.I don't get the details like eventName in google analytics.

Comment: It should work. I don't think this a problem in the meteor end of things. Are you sure analytics isn't getting it and you're looking in the right place?

Comment: Ya I have cross checked.Whenever  I click button the click action is shown in google analytics but other properties like eventName and other deatils is not shown.